# Check and add dates key and values to existing json object only if the values doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

the main object where data is to be added

```
let calendarObject = {
    "2017": [
        "2017/01/01",
        "2017/02/09"
    ],
    "2018": [
        "2018/01/01",
        "2018/02/05",
        "2018/05/16",
        "2018/08/02",
        "2018/10/08",
        "2018/10/09",
        "2018/10/11",
    ]
}
```

this is the array to be added to the last node of calendarObject

```
let dates = [
  "2017/10/23",
  "2017/11/14",
  "2018/10/05",
  "2018/10/07",
  "2018/10/08",
  "2018/10/09",
  "2018/10/13"
]
```

I want to merge the array like

```
let calendarObject = {
    "2017": [
        "2017/01/01",
        "2017/02/09",
        "2017/10/23",
        "2017/11/14"
    ],
    "2018": [
        "2018/01/01",
        "2018/02/05",
        "2018/05/16",
        "2018/08/02",
        "2018/10/08",
        "2018/10/09",
        "2018/10/11",
        "2018/10/05",
        "2018/10/07",
        "2018/10/13"
    ]
}
```

Is javascript sets must or what are the possible ways to do it efficiently?

I can check the availability of element in the array loop

```
calendarObject[year].indexOf(dates[index]) === -1 ? NaN : NaN
```

i'm stuck with objects, sets and arrays or what's the best alternative to work with these type of datas?

Comment: Using array of object for this data is fine. Do you have any specific problem with pushing those items?

Comment: datesArray.forEach((date, index) =>{
                 let dateYear = dates.split('/')[0];
                 calendarObject[dateYear].push(dates);
            });


is this the only solution

Comment: No, not _the only solution_. It looks fine, but you should use and push the `date` variable not the `dates` (whole array). If performance is the key, you should only consider improving your code when it noticeably slow down your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
datesArray.forEach((date, index) =>{
    let dateYear = dates.split('/')[0];
    calendarObject[dateYear].push(dates);
});
```

should work if you change the `dates` references in your function body into `date`.

> and what if dateYear was "2019" which is out of object bound the console will throw an error like "cannot read property [2019] of undefined" or sth like that

You can check the existence of the property for a year before pushing the item:

```
datesArray.forEach(date => {
    let dateYear = date.split('/')[0];
    if ( !calendarObject[dateYear] ) {
      // define a object property for a non-existent year
      calendarObject[dateYear] = {};
    }
    calendarObject[dateYear].push(date);
});
```

> what are the other methods for improving performance?

You should consider improving performance of your code only when it *noticeably* slow down your application. Since you have a small array, the `forEach` loop should work fast enough. If you have a larger array you can replace the `.forEach` with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
datesArray.forEach((date, index) =>{
    let dateYear = dates.split('/')[0];
    calendarObject[dateYear].push(dates);
});
```

this can be one solution

Comment: and what if dateYear was "2019" which is out of object bound
the console will throw an error like "cannot read property [2019] of undefined" or sth like that